# SolrJ version mismatch while merging 2 projects

Tags: java, maven-3, solrj

I have 2 java projects which developed using Solrj.

Project 1 -> using solrj 4.10.1

Project 2 -> using solrj 5.2.1

Now, I am trying to merge both the projects to single project.

I tried including both version of jars in maven, still same issue. 
If I try including only major version, I'm getting some of the classes(4.10.1) are deprecated and some interfaces are unavailable in it.

`<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
        <version>4.10.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
      <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.1</version>
    </dependency>`

In simple:Few Packages of same project uses different jars.

example:
Package1/Module1 uses : Solrj Jar version 4.10.1

Package2 uses : Solrj Jar version 5.2.1

Is there any way to merge this projects in best way, without change old project ? I am totally stuck here.

Comment: You forgot to mention what exactly yout issue is. Besinde that 2 versions of the same jar will definitly not work in maven. You guess should try updating to the newer version.

Answer (score 0):

If both projects are under the same Maven project (pom.xml), you need to update (or downgrade) one of the implementation. Both need to use the same SolrJ version. It shouldn't be too hard to update. You can find some details in [Solr Wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Major+Changes+from+Solr+4+to+Solr+5).